# Can Parallel.For Execute the Same Action (Same Index) More than Once?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

The documentation says otherwise ("The body delegate is invoked once for each value in the iteration range").

However, we have observed behavior that would be explained if the same Action were being executed more-or-less simultaneously by different threads.

I am asking about the simplest overload: `Parallel.For(Int32, Int32, Action<Int32>)`.

Comment: You would be better off looking for problems in your own code rather than hope that the TPL is broken.  It's not like this is edge functionality in TPL, it's very mainstream.  What other explanation could there be for the observed behaviour?  Add debug code to the delegate if nothing jumps out at you.

Comment: @Steve, with all due respect, it was not the TPL that I thought might be "broken", but the documentation. There are a number of places in .NET where a given delegate might be invoked in parallel (_e.g._, race to initialize). Yes, those are Funcs not Actions, but I've been surprised by .NET before. No harm in asking (or so I thought).

Comment: @WillMontgomery, the TPL is designed in a way that avoids threading issues, like race conditions. That doesn't mean you don't have to be careful with your own code, but it does mean you can depend on the face that the library functions behave the way you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it *will* be executed once for each value. Have a look at where else you're sharing any variables between multiple actions - I'm 99.99% sure you'll find your action *isn't* being executed twice with the same argument.

Comment: Parallel.For wasn't invoking the Action more than once; instead Parallel.For was being invoked in parallel with itself due to a bad declaration of lock object (local/instance when should have been global/static). So the same Action _was_ actually being executed more-or-less simultaneously by different threads. Unfortunately, the report of the problem alleged that the error had manifested in one object instance, when really it had occurred in a different instance (both derived from the same base type, so both had the same method containing Parallel.For). Anyway, thanks.